# Migrating bool value to SQL Server in AWS

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, amazon-web-services

From [Amazon's doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.SQLServer.html) it seems that there is one workaround for handling `bool` value while moving it from Postgres to SQL Server.

*Currently, boolean data types in a PostgreSQL source are migrated to a SQLServer target as the bit data type with inconsistent values. As a workaround, precreate the table with a VARCHAR(1) data type for the column (or let AWS DMS create the table). Then have downstream processing treat an "F" as False and a "T" as True.*

Has anyone tried an alternative way? Maybe attaching a python script that would be triggered by DMS?

Any alternative ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following transformation to the mapping:

```
    {
        \"rule-type\": \"transformation\",
        \"rule-id\": \"ruleId\",
        \"rule-name\": \"ruleName\",
        \"rule-action\": \"change-data-type\",
        \"rule-target\": \"column\",
        \"object-locator\": {
            \"schema-name\": \"sourceSchema\",
            \"table-name\": \"sourceTable\",
            \"column-name\": \"sourceColumn\"
        },
        \"data-type\": {
             \"type\": \"boolean\"
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As DMS is having issues with converting to BIT datatype, go with VARCHAR(1) datatype as they are suggesting and migrate the data.

In SQL Server bit datatype, false is treated as 0 & true is treated as 1.[Bit on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> The string values TRUE and FALSE can be converted to bit values: TRUE
> is converted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0.

Later, follow the below steps, as a downstream process.

1. Update the table with 1, 0 corresponding to true, false.

```sql
UPDATE <TableName>
SET <columnName> = CASE <ColumnName> WHEN 'F' THEN '0' WHEN 'T' THEN '1' END
```

2. Now, convert the datatype to bit

```sql
ALTER TABLE <TableName>
ALTER COLUMN <columnName> BIT NULL
```

Comment: Not really an option - we're looking for a solution without DDL (so no "alters" afterwards). And it should be upstream, not downstream. We've already tried changing the destination type - instead of bit, e.g. nullable smallint. So far we've established, that changing the column in the Aurora source to smallint does the trick (as long as it's in your control, which it isn't).